# Automatically max-height in JS

Tags: javascript, css

```
var DocHeight = $('.xxx').height();
$(".yyy").height(200 -DocHeight);
```

Hello, 
Above I show scheme changing height element depends on another element height, and I have question, is an option do the same but with max-height?

Comment: `$('.yyy').css('max-height', $('.xxx').css('max-height'));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any css attribute can be set using .css (if you use jquery of course). So basically you do something like this:

```
$(".yyy").css('max-height', (200 - DocHeight) + ' px');
```

Note that in this case you have to manually add 'px' because .height() makes the conversion automatically, now you need to specify unit of measure (I'm assuming pixels from your example).

More examples here: http://api.jquery.com/css/

I also assumed that you wanted just to set the max-height. If you want also to get the max-height you can do it in a similar matter:

```
var DocHeight = $('.xxx').css('max-height');
$(".yyy").css('max-height', DocHeight);
```

Note that in this case DocHeight comes exactly as it is defined in css so something like '100px' or '10%'. You need to manually convert it to a number if you want to compute something based on it (as you can see I removed the '200 -' part from the second instruction since that would've been invalid because you would be subtracting a string from a number).